# jQuery - making easy long code short (looping I guess)?

Tags: jquery, loops

I have a code like this:

```
 $("#item-1").hover(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();   
        $("#item-text").stop().animate({marginLeft: "0px"});
        $("#item-1-image").animate({opacity: 1});
    })  

 $("#item-1").mouseout(function() {
    $("#item-1-image").animate({opacity: 0});
 })
```

I have to repeat this for exactly 10 times changing all "item-1" to "item-2", "item-3" etc.

How to do that?

[edit]

What's the best/shortest way - because actually I know how to force it to work, but it's not an elegant way ;)

Comment: what does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be doing `hover()` and `mouseout()`.

The `.hover()` method accepts 2 functions representing `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Give the elements a common class, then extract the number from the ID

```
$(".someClass").hover(function(e) { 
      var num = this.id.split('-').pop();
      e.preventDefault();   
      $("#item-text").stop().animate({marginLeft: "0px"});
      $("#item-" + num + "-image").animate({opacity: 1});
 }, function() {
      var num = this.id.split('-').pop();
      $("#item-" + num + "-image").animate({opacity: 0});
 });
```

If you can't add a class for some reason, you can do a loop, but you need to use a javascript closure to retain the value of the index for the handlers.

```
for(var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {

    (function( num ) {
        $("item-" + i).hover(function(e) { 
              e.preventDefault();   
              $("#item-text").stop().animate({marginLeft: "0px"});
              $("#item-" + num + "-image").animate({opacity: 1});
         }, function() {
              $("#item-" + num + "-image").animate({opacity: 0});
         });
    })( i );

}
```

Comment: It works fine I believe but how to change marginLeft dynamically? I forgot to say that it should be 0 for the first item 250px for the 2nd item, 500 for the 3rd item. etc. I'm trying "500 * i" but doesn't seem to work. Thanks a lot anyways!

Comment: @formicz `(num - 1) * 250` you mean? Note the shift from 1-index to 0-index, the correct scale factor, and the use of `num` vs `i` (which is *shared* across all handlers!)

Comment: @fornicz - If you're using the second example, do `250 * (num - 1)`. The reason is the same reason we're using `num` inside the handlers for the selector. By the time the handler runs, the loop is finished and `i === 11`. Since we created a closure, and passed `i` into it, referencing it with the local variable `num`, the value of `num` will persist, so it will always be the same number it was when the closure was created in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The hover event should handle the over and out events just fine. If you are stuck with these ids you can use a `^=` to select ids that start with "item-".

```
$("div[id^='#item-']").hover(
    function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find("p").stop().animate({marginLeft: "0px"});
        $(this).find("img").animate({opacity: 1});
    }, 
    function() {
        $(this).find("img").animate({opacity: 0});
    }
);
```

You're must better off using one css class as these selectors would be much easier to work with.

Comment: How can you be certain the `<img>` to animate is nested in the item, and that there's only one in there? (Also, be sure to remove the `#` from the original selector.) ;o)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular javascript for each loop.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    $("#item-" + i).hover( ...
}
```

Comment: You may want to review your JavaScript in the above; it's not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=1;i<=10;++i){
  $('#item-'+i).hover(...).mouseout(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=1;i<11;i++)
{
 $("#item-"+i).hover(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();   
        $("#item-text").stop().animate({marginLeft: "0px"});
        $("#item-"+i+"-image").animate({opacity: 1});
    })  

 $("#item-"+i).mouseout(function() {
    $("#item-"+i+"-image").animate({opacity: 0});
 }) 
}
```

Comment: This won't work because the value of `i` in the handlers will be the last value from the end of `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".item").hover(function(e) {  
      e.preventDefault();   
    $("#item-text").stop().animate({marginLeft: "0px"});
    $(".itemImage[number='"+$(this).attr("number")+"']").animate({opacity: 1});
},function() {
    $(".itemImage[number='"+$(this).attr("number")+"']").animate({opacity: 0});
});
```

1. Use hover for both events
2. Use classes and a attribute, no ids with numbers